# Creating trace file in sumo for NS3

Tags: openstreetmap, sumo

i have generated a OSM senario using OSMWebWizard then i used sumo 1.18.0 to generate the trace file using the command "sumo -c osm.sumocfg --fcd-output trace.xml". but the line is not working and it gives me "unknown option '--fcd-output'".

please assist and appreciate it

I tried the command "sumo -c osm.sumocfg --fcd-output trace.xml".
When running the command i expect it to produce the file trace.xml